# is it possible to read device isochronous endpoints using host interrupt endpoints?

Tags: embedded, usb, libusb, firmware

We are developing an example where device continuously stream data through an isochronous IN endpoint. Now my question was as interrupt and isochronous have lot of similarities :

1. Max 1024 packets in USB HS
2. both are for bandwidth guarantee.
3. Host polls device every micro frame.

can I use my host interrupt endpoint to configure is to read from device's isochronous endpoints ?

device isochronous endpoints is following :

```
===>Endpoint Descriptor<===
bLength: 0x07
bDescriptorType: 0x05
bEndpointAddress: 0x81 -> Direction: IN - EndpointID: 1
bmAttributes: 0x05 -> Isochronous Transfer Type, Synchronization Type = Asynchronous, Usage Type = Data Endpoint
wMaxPacketSize: 0x0180 = 1 transactions per microframe, 0x180 max bytes
bInterval: 0x01
```

I understand there is NACK/ACK token in the interrupt endpoints , but let say if device ignores this NACK/ACK token can I still communicate with device using my interrupt endpoints ?